# What to do if App crashes or is closed while writing a file?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

So I've found that it's possible for the app to crash or be closed while in the process of writing a file. If this happens (especially if it's a big file) this tends to overwrite the file that existed before and leave a new file with 0 bytes in it.

So, what do I do in this case? Should I be writing all files to temporary files first, then using a Rename call to overwrite the old file? Should I be including a waiting function in the UnhandledException event?

Comment: Considering what you said - writing to a new file sounds like a reasonable option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UnhandledException` event will not help you.. No code can be 100% guaranteed to be run. Not even `UnhandledException` event.. The first approach you already have on mind is a common one.. i.e. use a temp file.

Comment: Very good point, as it won't catch Native exceptions I've noticed, but didn't consider. I think I'm going to go with the temp file approach.